# MySQL sever configuration failed

Tags: mysql

Beginning configuration step: Writing configuration file

Saving my.ini configuration file...
Saved my.ini configuration file.
Ended configuration step: Writing configuration file

Beginning configuration step: Updating Windows Firewall rules

Adding a Windows Firewall rule for MySQL8 on port 3306.
Attempting to add a Windows Firewall rule with command: netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="Port 3306" protocol=TCP localport=3306 dir=in action=allow
Ok.

Successfully added the Windows Firewall rule.
Adding a Windows Firewall rule for MySQL8 on port 33060.
Attempting to add a Windows Firewall rule with command: netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="Port 33060" protocol=TCP localport=33060 dir=in action=allow
Ok.

Successfully added the Windows Firewall rule.
Ended configuration step: Updating Windows Firewall rules

Beginning configuration step: Adjusting Windows service

Attempting to grant Network Service require filesystem permissions.
Granted permissions.
Adding new service
New service added
Ended configuration step: Adjusting Windows service

Beginning configuration step: Initializing database (may take a long time)

Attempting to run MySQL Server with --initialize-insecure option...
Starting process for MySQL Server 8.0.31...
Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --console --initialize-insecure=on --lower-case-table-names=1...
Using jemalloc.dll for my_malloc and ut::malloc etc.
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Empty value for 'open_files_limit' specified.
Process for mysqld, with ID 7304, was run successfully and exited with code 1.
Failed to start process for MySQL Server 8.0.31.
Database initialization failed.
Ended configuration step: Initializing database (may take a long time)

i need some help..............

Answer (score 0):

Encoutered the very same problem. My solution in Win10 was:

Go to c:\programdata\mysql\mysql installer for windows\manifest\templates

Change the template-file for you version. Also set innodb_thread_concurrency.

Unfortunately, even then the initialisation fails so you would have to do manually. I did it by:

- go into the bin-directory of mysql and do a manual 'mysqld --initialize-insecure --user=mysql' in c:\program files\mysql\mysql server 8.0\bin
- copy the data-directory from c:\program files\mysql\mysql server 8.0 to c:\programdata\mysql\mysql server 8.0